# какие еще могут быть способы решения этой задачи?

Tags: javascript

Есть четырехзначное число, которое вы должны разбить на тысячи, сотни,
десятки и единицы.
Входные данные:
1. Четырехзначное число (1000 < число < 9999)
Вывести в формате:
t - тысячи
s - сотни
d - десятки
e - единицы
Пример:
4587
Вывести в виде:
4 -тысячи
5 -сотни
8-десятки
7-единиц
Решение должно работать для любого четырехзначного числа.

Я сделала вот так

```
var nummer = 4587;
var tt = Math.floor(nummer/1000);
var ss = Math.floor((nummer%1000)/100);
var dd =  Math.floor(((nummer%1000)%100)/10);
var ee = (((nummer%1000)%100)%10);


document.write(tt +" - тысячи<br/>" +ss+ " - сотни<br/>" +dd+ " - десятки<br/>" + ee + " - едениц");
document.write("<br/>");
```

Comment: Сколько угодно. В вашем решении неплохо бы убрать лишние действия (не смысла брать остаток от деления на 1000, а потом на 100) и поправил грамматику. Ну и document.write это что-то из замшелых 90-х, console.log наше всё

Answer (score 4):

Ну, например, можно распарсить как строку:

```js
var num = 4587;
var str = num.toString();

var tt = str.charAt(0);
var ss = str.charAt(1);
var dd = str.charAt(2);
var ee = str.charAt(3);

console.log(tt + " - тысячи\n" + ss + " - сотни\n" + dd + " - десятки\n" + ee + " - единиц");
```

Comment: Вместо charAt короче индекс использовать :)

Comment: @AlexeyTen угу, а вместо toString можно прибавить "". Но так как есть читабельнее :)

Comment: Ну не знаю, `str[0]` я быстрее пойму :)